# How can i find the coordinates of distinct values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 3 3 0 0 0 4 4 0 0 0 5 5 5 5 0 0 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 6 6 6 6 6 6 0 6 6 6 6]
 [0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 3 0 0 0 4 4 0 0 5 5 5 5 5 5 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 0 0 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6]
 [1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 3 0 0 0 4 4 0 5 5 5 0 0 5 5 5 0 2 2 0 0 2 2 0 0 0 2 2 0 0 6 6 0 0 6 6 6 0 0 6 6]
 [1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 3 0 0 0 4 4 0 5 5 5 5 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 0 2 2 2 0 0 0 2 2 2 0 6 6 0 0 0 6 6 0 0 6 6]
 [1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 3 0 0 0 4 4 0 0 5 5 5 5 5 5 0 0 2 2 0 2 2 2 0 0 0 2 2 2 0 6 6 0 0 0 6 6 0 0 6 6]
 [0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 7 0 0 0 3 3 0 0 0 4 4 0 0 0 0 5 5 5 5 5 0 2 2 0 2 2 2 0 0 0 2 2 2 0 6 6 0 0 0 6 6 0 0 6 6]]
```

The following is a connected components list of lists (50 x 10), let's call it `labels` , what i want is to create a dictionary where the numbers except `0` are a key of that dictionary, and the value correspondent to that key should be the coordinates for example `[xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax]`,

Let's take 1 for example:

```
{'1': [0,10,1,9], '2': [......}
```

Being new to python, I found it hard to write a program to do that from scratch (not the dictionary creation and filling but finding the coordinates). Is there a way inside numpy that can do that for example `np.unique(labels)` would help me identify unique labels values.

Comment: Can you explain WHY for the key `'1'` the value is  `[0,10,1,9]`, how are the coordinates calculated?

Comment: Sure and i just edited the question it should be `[0,10,1,9]`  the first `0` is the minimal coordinate x where `1` appears as we can see it appears 3 times on that column and the last time `1` appears is on column `10` same analogy for the last 2 terms but for rows.

Comment: Understood. working on a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html). It returns two arrays:
- the first contains row indeces `y`
- the second contains column indeces `x`.

```
import nupmy as np

arr = np.array(labels)

stats = dict()
for i in np.unique(arr):
    if i == 0:
        continue
    else:
        wh = np.where(arr == i)
        stats[i] = [wh[1].min(), wh[1].max(), wh[0].min(), wh[0].max()]

> {1: [0, 10, 1, 9],
   2: [29, 41, 2, 9],
   3: [13, 14, 4, 9],
   4: [18, 19, 4, 9],
   5: [21, 28, 4, 9],
   6: [43, 53, 4, 9],
   7: [9, 9, 9, 9]}
```